# Is there a cleaner way to write this radio toggle component in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

Basically I want a class name added to a radio toggle button when it is selected or checked. I've done the below, but it seems i've essentially written the same thing twice. Is there a shorter/cleaner way to write this component sticking with the same functionality?

```
import React from 'react';
import classnames from 'classnames';

class RadioToggle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: 'yes',
      value2: 'no',
      isNo: false,
      isYes: false,
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.handleClick2 = this.handleClick2.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    this.setState({
      value: e.target.value,
      isYes: true,
      isNo: false
    });
  }

  handleClick2(e) {
    this.setState({
      value2: e.target.value2,
      isNo: true,
      isYes: false
    });
  }

  render() {
    let classes = classnames('radioButton', {active: this.state.value && this.state.isYes == true ? 'selected' : null});
    let classes2 = classnames('radioButton', {active: !this.state.value2 && this.state.isNo == true ? 'selected' : null})
    return (
      <div>
        <input className={classes} type="radio" name="yesno" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleClick}/>Yes
        <input className={classes2} type="radio" name="yesno" value={this.state.value2} onChange={this.handleClick2}/>No
      </div>
        );
  }
}

export default RadioToggle;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like the below.  The goal is to use a single value from which you can reliable base each input from.

You are, in essence, using two radio fields to hold a boolean value.

A few questions to think about as you continue to build out this component:

1. Is a value always required?  Will it always be either `true` or `false`?  Or could it be blank/`undefined`?
2. Could you use a checkbox instead?  A checkbox is a better fit for the `true` or `false` contexts like this.

   ```
   import React from 'react';
   import classnames from 'classnames';

   class RadioToggle extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
         value: undefined
       };
     }

     handleClick(e, value) {
       this.setState({
         value: value
       });
     }

     render() {
       return (
         <div>
           <input
             className={classnames('radioButton', {active: this.state.value === true})}
             type="radio"
             name="yesno"
             value={this.state.value === true}
             onChange={this.handleClick.bind(this, true)}
           />
           Yes

           <input
             className={classnames('radioButton', {active: this.state.value === false})}
             type="radio"
             name="yesno"
             value={this.state.value === false}
             onChange={this.handleClick.bind(this, false)}
           />
           No
         </div>
           );
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks. yes value must always be yes or no. I suppose on inital load it will be undefined but i'll need to add validation anyway.